# How to change object color in viewport in 2.8?

Tags: 3d-view, color, object-mode

Is it possible in Blender 2.80 to change the color of objects in the viewport? Like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KqmSFdY7UgY) in the previous versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The setting is still in the same place.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I was looking at the wrong viewport display menu... (the one in the object menu)

Comment: @wohe1 No problem. Please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Comment: I will in one minute :) (for some reason it can't be marked as solved immediately)

Comment: @wohe1 Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

For anyone not wanting to view the video (or are also satellite internet users like myself) the step by step solution is thus:

1. Select the object
2. Select the Materials tab in the bottom-right menu
3. Create a new material
4. Scroll down and you'll see a bunch of collapsed menus
5. Expand / Uncollapse the menu titled "Viewport Display"
6. Adjust the settings in here to your heart's content (:

And yes, these do persist through both edit and object modes.

Edit: Ah satellite internet.. the picture just loaded in. My apologies, it's likely that anyone could have figured this step by step process out via the image. I had to sort it out via zoom and enhance 8 bit rendition of a 144p video x.x I swear there's a special version of 144p meant for people with extra low bitrate.

Answer (score 3):

There's another way to do this without committing to making a material (in case you already have some).

Go to *Object Properties > Viewport Display* and pick a colour.

[image: Change the colour]

Then click the little dropdown arrow next to your viewport render settings and under *Color*, click *Object*. This will force your viewport to color objects the way you want rather than what their material says.

[image: Force object coloring]